# Ansible issue while attempting to update a file using replace module

Tags: ansible

I'm unsure if you've encountered this issue before
I'm using the `ansible replace module` to update a file located in the `/etc/systemd/` directory. Although the log shows that the update was successfully applied, upon checking the file, it appears that no changes have actually been made. Please see below.

**Code:**

```
cat vars.yml 
dns_server: "192.168.22.12 192.168.22.13"
#dns_server: "192.168.22.12,192.168.22.13"
```

```
- name: Handle user DNS entry for /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    DNS_ENTRY: "{{ dns_server is defined | regex_replace(',', ' ') }}"
  when: 
    - dns_server is defined and dns_server is defined | regex_search(',')

- name: Use original user entry if no comma found
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    DNS_ENTRY: "{{ dns_server }}"
  when: 
    - dns_server is defined and not dns_server| regex_search(',')

- name: Ensure DNS configuration is set in resolved.conf
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
    regexp: '^#DNS='
    replace: 'DNS={{ DNS_ENTRY }}'
```

**Follow the ansible outcome:**

```
TASK [Handle user DNS entry for /etc/systemd/resolved.conf] ********************
task path: /opt/vi/firstboot/ansible/tasks/10-network.yml:33
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

TASK [Use original user entry if no comma found] *******************************
task path: /opt/vi/firstboot/ansible/tasks/10-network.yml:39
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "DNS_ENTRY": "192.168.22.12 192.168.22.13"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Ensure DNS configuration is set in resolved.conf] ************************
task path: /opt/vi/firstboot/ansible/tasks/10-network.yml:45
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/replace.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1398ho9ozv7y/tmpfbiy0ps4 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995/AnsiballZ_replace.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995/AnsiballZ_replace.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995/AnsiballZ_replace.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1709713866.0024374-2195-81793838038995/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
changed: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "after": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": false,
            "before": null,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "group": null,
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/etc/systemd/resolved.conf",
            "regexp": "^#DNS=",
            "replace": "DNS=192.168.22.12 192.168.22.13",
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "unsafe_writes": false,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "1 replacements made"
}
```

however, when I see in the file itself, nothing has changed

```
 cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the resolved.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

Any idea what can be?  Because I still not get why it is not update the file

Comment: The module *replace* works as expected. You must be missing something. Try the [mre] below.

Answer (score 1):

Given the file for testing

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/resolved.conf 
#DNS=
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: /tmp/resolved.conf
        regexp: '^#DNS='
        replace: 'DNS={{ DNS_ENTRY }}'
      vars:
        DNS_ENTRY: 192.168.22.12 192.168.22.13
```

gives (abridged, running with --check --diff options)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD
  ...
--- before: /tmp/resolved.conf
+++ after: /tmp/resolved.conf
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#DNS=
+DNS=192.168.22.12 192.168.22.13
```

Comment: This was quite helpful, it enabled me to pinpoint the root cause of the issue. Interestingly, it's not directly related to Ansible, but rather to the specific OS distribution we're using. Upon applying the Ansible task, we rebooted the server, inadvertently causing the loss of these Ansible settings